# VBA: Name Sheet in Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables

I have one cell with all sheet name write in this way: "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3".
So I insert this value in single variable SheetNames as String.

Now, I need to get single sheet name and insert.
My code is:

```
varSheets = Array(FogliArray)
    'varSheets = Array("Other", "Research", "IT")

    lngShtCnt = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each varSheet In varSheets
        With wkbSource.Worksheets(varSheet)
```

If I use varSheets = Array("Other", "Research", "IT") all work correctly.
But if I use varSheets = Array(FogliArray) where FogliArray is variable that contains all sheet name ("Other", "Research", "IT") not works.

Please, can you help me?
Many thanks,
Andrea.

Comment: Use `Split` and you may have to replace the quotes too.

Comment: so `FogliArray` refers to one cell?

Comment: @BigBen you may want to post it as an aswer?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Split` to return an array of the worksheet names, `Replace` the quotes, and `Trim$` the spaces, something like the following:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim FogliList As String
    FogliList = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    FogliList = Replace(FogliList, """", "") ' no quotes

    Dim FogliArray
    FogliArray = Split(FogliList, ",")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(FogliArray) To UBound(FogliArray)
        Dim FoglioName As String
        FoglioName = Trim$(FogliArray(i))

        With wkbSource.Worksheets(FoglioName)
            ' Do whatever you wanted to do
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```